# Ещё бы ведь

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно оформить стык этих слов?

Например:

"Он положил ружьё. Ещё бы (?) ведь здесь не стреляют".

И как оформить в варианте без "ведь":

"Он положил ружьё. Ещё бы (?) здесь не стреляют".

Лично я бы поставил в первом случае тире, а во втором двоеточие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире и двоеточие вносят ненужный пояснительный характер. Можно оформить по-разному: с запятой или с восклицательном знаком.

"Он положил ружьё. Ещё бы, ведь здесь не стреляют". "Он положил ружьё. Ещё бы! Ведь здесь не стреляют".
Ещё бы, здесь не стреляют". Ещё бы! Здесь не стреляют".
Восклицательный знак ставится в конце слова обращения, междометного предложения или предложения-обращения, если оно произносится с восклицательной интонацией: Еще бы!( Г.);  Верно! (Вс. Ив.); Нет, нет! (Крым.) Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник-практикум.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставила и в первом и во втором случае запятые.